# VS Code Inspect Elements

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have been using Adobe Dreamweaver (2005) for doing web development. I recent switched to VS Code. Dreamweaver has a built in browser where I can inspect a HTML element and it will find it in the editor immediately. This comes in really handy especially when I'm working on messy projects that have been evolving for years. I really like a lot of things about VS Code but this feature is important in saving me a lot of time. Is there any way to get this feature in VS Code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is now built into every major browser in the form of dev tools: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open#elements

You can simply click on an element, and in a separate pane, you will be shown the corresponding code.

You can also link DevTools directly to VS code via the extension debugger for chrome in the VS code marketplace - or debugger for Firefox, etc.

However, I recommend starting with the browser dev tools if you're not familiar with them already, as they are simple to use and require no configuration.

Comment: I am fully aware of chromes DevTools. Even though this helps I still have to go to my editior and look for the code for a certain element after inspecting it inside of Chrome. Also, if I understand correctly, Debugger for Chrome requires you to be working from a local web server. Most of the work I do is done with FTP or vpn's to remote servers.

Comment: I found somewhat of a compromise. I created a macro that copy the html element in chrome and pastes it into search on vs code. It works good enough.